# How to get the physical address of the potentially conflicting memory lines(cache lines within the same cache set)

Tags: c++, c, caching, memory, memory-management

I've read a paper called [Last-Level Cache Side-Channel Attacks are Practical](http://palms.ee.princeton.edu/system/files/SP_vfinal.pdf). In the paper, it tried to construct an eviction set. According to the paper, we shall allocate a buffer (backed up by large pages) of at least twice the size of the LLC and select a set of potentially conflicting memory lines within the buffer,i.e., lines whose
addresses have the same set index bits.

If I've got the set index, how can I get the address of each cache line within this set?

For example, I've allocate a 6MB buffer backed by 2MB page(using C `mmap()` function) and got the base address of the page. According to the basic cache addressing, I can get set index through method in the picture. [image: simple cache addressing]

But how to get the whole addresses of the cache lines within the same set?

Comment: It is hardware specific and could be impossible. Very probably different on ARM and on x86-64, and probably different on AMD Ryzen and on old Intel Xeon X3430